# join multiple tables using linq query and orderby the tables

Tags: join, linq-to-entities

I have the 4 tables. i want to create linq query for using *joins* and fetching the data by who are all active employers. my tables are,

**1. Jobs**

```
 EmployerId
```

**2. Employerregistrationddetails**

```
  Employerid

  planid

  amount
```

**3. EmployerPlans**

```
  planid

  alerts
```

**4. AlertDones**

```
  employerid

  alertssent
```

In the Jobs table  employerid equal to *Emp_Reg_Details.employerId* and *emp_reg_details.planId* equals to *employerplans.planId* and *Employerplans.alerts* equals *alertdones.alertssent* means it will order first the above conditions then the rest of the jobs will  order..

i put linq query for this.. but it is not exactly working.. My query is

```
 return (from job in _db.Jobs 
         join employerregdetails in _db.EmployerRegistrationDetails 
             on job.OrganizationId equals employerregdetails.EmployerId into e
         join ep in _db.EmployerPlans 
             on emp.PlanId equals ep.EmployerPlanId
         join alr in _db.AlertsDones 
             on ep.Alerts equals alr.AlertsSent
         from emp in e.DefaultIfEmpty()

         orderby job.OrganizationId != -1 descending, 
                 job.OrganizationId != null descending
         orderby job.OrganizationId != -1 descending, 
                 alr.EmployerId == job.OrganizationId descending, 
                 job.CreatedDate descending
         select job);
```

If i use the above query i have an error `emp.PlanId`. It is not taking the emp variable.. I did any mistake please clarify me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not see the `emp` variable because it has defined after line you want to refer that, you need to define emp before this line:

```
join ep in _db.EmployerPlans on emp.PlanId equals ep.EmployerPlanId
```

like this:

```
return (from job in _db.Jobs 
        join employerregdetails in _db.EmployerRegistrationDetails 
            on job.OrganizationId equals employerregdetails.EmployerId into e
        from emp in e.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join ep in _db.EmployerPlans on emp.PlanId equals ep.EmployerPlanId
```

but notice, you maybe get error when a `jobs` does not have any `EmployerRegistrationDetails`, because you try to use `left join`, and in this case `emp` is `null`